# Manifest does not have `short_name`, Manifest does not have `name`

Tags: php, json, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

When running the Google Chrome audit i'm getting the following errors:

`` Web app manifest does not meet the installability requirementsFailures: Manifest does not have `short_name`, Manifest does not have `name`. ``

[photo of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye3Iq.png)

as well as

`` Is not configured for a custom splash screenFailures: Manifest does not have a PNG icon of at least 512px, Manifest does not have `name`. ``

[photo of second error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwDTn.png)

I have an `app-files` in the root directory as well as the manifest.json which looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "This is my long name",
  "short_name": "short name",
  "theme_color": "#cd061d",
  "background_color": "#ececec",
  "display": "browser",
  "Scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/index.php",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "app-images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "app-images/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "app-images/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "app-images/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "app-images/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "app-images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "app-images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "app-images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction on what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

A site.webmanifest from a favicon generator i used blocked my custom manifest.json file.